# Error Compiler gem 'private-gem-server'

Tags: ruby, rubygems

i get an error while compile gem 'private_gem_server' on my windows, ActiveRuby with gcc

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    gem_make.out:
    current directory: C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/ext/thin_parser
                C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180724-39224-y3ahsm.rb extconf.rb
                checking for main() in -lc... *** extconf.rb failed ***
                Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
                libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
                need configuration options.

                Provided configuration options:
                    --with-opt-dir
                    --without-opt-dir
                    --with-opt-include
                    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
                    --with-opt-lib
                    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
                    --with-make-prog
                    --without-make-prog
                    --srcdir=.
                    --curdir
                    --ruby=C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
                    --with-thin_parser-dir
                    --without-thin_parser-dir
                    --with-thin_parser-include
                    --without-thin_parser-include=${thin_parser-dir}/include
                    --with-thin_parser-lib
                    --without-thin_parser-lib=${thin_parser-dir}/lib
                    --with-clib
                    --without-clib
                C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
                You have to install development tools first.
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:765:in `try_func'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:997:in `block in have_library'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
                    from C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:992:in `have_library'
                    from extconf.rb:4:in `'

                To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

                  C:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/thin-1.7.2/mkmf.log

                extconf failed, exit code 1

    mkmf.log:

                "gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/SDK/ActiveRuby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/SDK/ActiveRuby/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/SDK/ActiveRuby/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-maybe-uninitialized conftest.c  -L. -LC:/SDK/ActiveRuby/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
                checked program was:
                /* begin */
                1: #include "ruby.h"
                2: 
                3: #include 
                4: #include 
                5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
                6: {
                7:   return 0;
                8: }
                /* end */
```

How to correct it, sorry i am newbie

Answer (score 1):

As written in error `You have to install development tools first.`

Development tools are used to compile gems with C-extensions.

So go to https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/, select corresponding ruby version **with devkit**, donwload and install it, but be prepared, ruby on windows will give you lots of headaches as newbie.